# virt-install complains "error: no such option: --network-bridge:br0"

Tags: centos, windows, virtual-machine, kvm

I was following [the directions here](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/KVM_Virtualization_in_RHEL_6_made_easy.pdf) to set up a VM in CentOS 6.4 i386/686.  But I'm getting this error:

```
$ sudo virt-install --network-bridge:br0 --name vm1 --ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1.img,size=10 --cdrom ~/winxp.iso
Usage: virt-install --name NAME --ram RAM STORAGE INSTALL [options]

virt-install: error: no such option: --network-bridge:br0
```

Sure enough, `virt-install --help` doesn't list that as an option.  But it also doesn't list `--cdrom`, `--disk`...

Does it mean I didn't set up `br0` right?  (I followed the guide pretty closely.  I wasn't sure how to verify that what it's looking for is present.)

I ought to specify, I have no GUI installed--used the 'minimal' ISO.

**UPDATE**

```
$ sudo -i brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0040caab50b8       no              eth0
virbr0          8000.525400dfd8ac       yes             virbr0-nic
```

Maybe I don't understand--I thought a VM needed an OS to be created? Or I guess you create the VM, and it's pretending to be bare metal, and then you can go into the VM and tell it to use a CD ISO as the CD drive, and install the OS from there?

So at this point with your modified XML file and restarted libvirtd, I have KVM running and vm1 running on it, ready to have an OS installed?

The thing is, virt-install still gives this error. IMO it for some reason doesn't have the switch named --network-bridge built into it, but I have no idea why that would be. Wrong version? Compiled without an option? I forgot to install a dependency of some kind? These all seem improbable to me, I thought network bridging is pretty standard for a VM, hence my posting a question here in the first place. :) Sorry if I'm babbling but I'm really just stuck on the virt-install command step.

Comment: see my comments in my answer, the switch you're using, `--network-bridge:br0` should be `--network bridge:br0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### typo

I see no reference to `--network-bridge` when I search either the [URL you reference to the PDF](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/KVM_Virtualization_in_RHEL_6_made_easy.pdf) nor the [original that the PDF derives from](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/2475.kvm-virtualization-made-easy.aspx). Fixing the switch to `virt-install` should resolve your issue. Here's the example from the documentation that I believe you're using:

```
# virt-install \
--network bridge:br0 \
--name vm1 \
--ram=1024 \
--vcpus=1 \
--disk path=/vm-images/vm1.img,size=10 \
--graphics none \ 
--location=http://my.server.com/pub/rhel6.1/install-x86_64/ \
--extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200"
```

### Other methods for setting up the network

Below are other ways that the bridge device can be created for a VM instead of using `virt-install`.

#### virt-manager

You can create the br0 network prior to spinning up VM's that use it. See here:

- http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/bridged-networking-virt-manager-083

[image: ss of virt-manager]

#### virsh

If you don't have access to a GUI or can't remote display `virt-manager` to another system that does you can create a network device using the command line tool, [`virsh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh).

First add the eth0 network device to the bridge, br0, by editing the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BRIDGE=br0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=[[your mac address]]
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=yes
PEERDNS=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Then create the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0` and add the following:

```
DEVICE=br0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp 
TYPE=Bridge
PEERNTP=yes
```

Next restart the network:

```
$ sudo service network restart
```

Now create a libvirt VM config `/etc/libvirt/qemu/<vmname>.xml` and add the following to it:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='11:22:33:44:55:66'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
</interface>
```

Now you can start up libvirtd, and the VM, you should see the br0 network when you run this command:

```
$ sudo -i brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.bcaec534c9e8   no      vnet5
                            vnet4
                            vnet3
                            vnet2
                            vnet1
                            vnet0
                            eth0
virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes
```

Comment: @Kev - yes if you don't have a GUI, you can use the command `virsh` to do things with KVM. Check out the man page, `man virsh`.

Comment: @Kev - sorry it's a bit confusing. Without using the GUI `virt-manager` it's a bit of a trial by committee and you have to use a couple of tools to do the work. `virsh` is used mainly to make modifications to the VM's config file, as I've described above.

Comment: sorry & thanks for letting me know.  I'll post an update in the question.

Comment: @Kev - I just reread your comments about the switch, `--network-bridge`, I don't have that switch in my version of `virt-install` on CentOS 5.8. My `virt-install` is part of this package, `python-virtinst`, version 0.400.3-13.el5.

Comment: Weird that that Dell guide mentions it, eh?  Oh you know what, I just figured it out.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Kev - that switch isn't `--network-bridge:br0` it's this: `--network bridge:br0`, see this document: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/2475.kvm-virtualization-made-easy.aspx

Comment: I know, I answered that already, that's what I figured out myself from the man page.  I gave you +1s for helping walk through the other part though.