# virt-install error: install methods 'cannot be specified for container guests'

Tags: centos, virtualization, kvm

I was following [the Dell RHEL VM guide](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/KVM_Virtualization_in_RHEL_6_made_easy.pdf) but working on CentOS 6.4 i386/686, and got to the virt-install step.  After [correcting a typo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82652/34450), I went back and deleted [the vm.xml file it was suggested I create](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82568/34450), and restarted libvirtd.

Now I get this error, which Google mainly returns github localization pages about:

```
$ sudo virt-install --network bridge:br0 --name vm1 --ram=1024 --vcpus=1 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1.img,size=4 --cdrom ~/winxp.iso
ERROR    Install methods (--location URL, --cdrom CD/ISO, --pxe, --import, --boot hd|cdrom|...) cannot be specified for container guests
```

What's a container guest and why can't I install with one?  What do I need to do to fix this so I can install Windows on KVM?  (And why does this, which is taken from a Dell guide, not work?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Linux container guests" are a different type of VM than a "KVM" VM.  You need to add `--virt-type`.  From [the docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/virt-install):

> --virt-type The hypervisor to install on. Example choices are kvm, qemu, xen, or kqemu. Availabile options are listed via 'virsh
>   capabilities' in the  tags.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was due to unnecessary packages being installed.  Therefore, the solution was to remove all the libvirt-related packages, then re-install just those that I needed, and then restart libvirtd.

The following five commands accomplished all this and resolved the problem:

```
yum remove qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer bridge-utils

yum install qemu-kvm qemu-img libvirt libvirt-client virt-install bridge-utils -y

systemctl stop libvirtd
systemctl start libvirtd
systemctl status libvirtd
```